# Not Found: /api/company_list/status='Pending' I want to filter by status, but I have an issue

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
    @api_view(['GET']) // that is my get query list
    def company_list(self):
        company_list = Company.objects.all()
        return Response(CompanySerializer(company_list, many=True).data)

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Company.objects.all()
        statusa = self.request.query_params.get('status', '')
        if statusa:
            return Company.objects.filter(status=statusa)
        return queryset
```

This is my status

```
status='Approved'
status='Pending'
```

That is my Url :

http://localhost:8000/api/company_list/status='Pending'

Comment: You should set `company_list=self.get_queryset()`, not `Company.objects.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I hope your problem is resolved

```
@api_view(['GET']) // that is my get query list
def company_list(self):
    company_list = self.get_queryset()
    return Response(CompanySerializer(company_list, many=True).data)

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Company.objects.all()
    statusa = self.request.query_params.get('status', '')
    if statusa:
        queryset = queryset.filter(status=statusa)

    return queryset
```